# Prove $\lim_{x\to-2}\frac{x+8}{x+3}=6 $ using $\epsilon-\delta$

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

> Prove:
>
> $$\lim_{x\to-2}\frac{x+8}{x+3}=6 $$

I started with:

$ |\frac{x+8}{x+3} - 6| < \epsilon  => |\frac{x+8-6x-18}{x+3} | < \epsilon => |\frac{-5x-10}{x+3} | < \epsilon =>| \frac{-5(x+2)}{x+3} | < \epsilon $

From the definition of limit we know that:

$ |x+2| <\delta $

Just don't know how to continue now... any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Take $\delta=min(\frac{1}{2},\frac{\epsilon}{10})>0$

Then $\forall x, |x+2| <\delta $, $|x+3|>\frac{1}{2}$, hence $$| \frac{-5(x+2)}{x+3} |\le 10|x+2| < \epsilon $$

The key is to select $\delta$ such that $x$ is closed to $-2$ compared with $-3$.

Comment: How did you know $|x+3| > \frac{1}{2} ?  $

Comment: @user1326293 Draw the line, label $-2$ and $-3$ on it. If $|x+2|=|x-(-2)|<\delta\le \frac{1}{2}$, what's the lower bound of the distance between $x$ and $-3$?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, I  need to know if that's the only condition that fits $\delta < \frac{1}{2} $ ? 
 if I were to take for example $ \delta < 1 $ would this work too? thanks!

Comment: @user1326293 The key is give $|x+3|$ a positive lower bound, so it is not unique but $1$ doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

First let us restrict $x$ such that $\vert x+2 \vert < 1/2$, i.e., $-5/2<x<-3/2$.

This means we have $1/2<x+3<3/2$, i.e., $\dfrac23 < \dfrac1{x+3} < 2$

Hence, we have
$$\left \vert \dfrac{-5(x+2)}{x+3}\right \vert = 5 \left \vert \dfrac{x+2}{x+3}\right \vert < 10 \vert x+2 \vert$$

Hence, choose your $\delta = \min(1/2,\epsilon/10)$ to ensure that $\left \vert \dfrac{-5(x+2)}{x+3}\right \vert$ is less than $\epsilon$.